# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xampp

Tags: php, foreach

I am creating a Content Management System and when I run the following code, an error happens

```
<?php foreach ( $results['articles'] as $article ) { ?>

        <li>
          <h2>
            <span class="pubDate"><?php echo date('j F Y', $article->publicationDate)?></span><a href=".?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?php echo $article->id?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->title )?></a>
          </h2>
          <p class="summary"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->summary )?></p>
        </li>

<?php } ?>
```

I hope to run it without any error message

Comment: whats `print_r($results['articles']);` return

Comment: @tim it returns " Notice: Undefined variable: results "

Comment: well that's the problem

Comment: please provide the whole script or the $result variable definition